# Git push fails after authentication

Tags: apache-2.4, git, sles

I'm deploying git server on our production SUSE 12 SP3 to be accessed via Visual Studio. First I made a working test vm with git that works fine, but after I recreated all the work on our production server, `git push` fails after user authenticationwith following errors:

```
error: Cannot access URL http://git.sevlinux.local/git/test.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://git.sevlinux.local/git/test.git'
```

Here's my Apache conf:

```
*:80     git.sevlinux.local (/etc/apache2/vhosts.d/git.sevlinux.powertech.conf:1)
*:443    cryptedweb.sevlinux.local (/etc/apache2/vhosts.d/technet.sevlinux.powertech.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/srv/www"
Main DocumentRoot: "/srv/www/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: SYSCONFIG
Define: SSL
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="wwwrun" id=30
Group: name="www" id=8
```

And Virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                            
    DocumentRoot /srv/git                                        
    ServerName git.sevlinux.local                            
    ServerAdmin nidrax@local

    <Directory /srv/git>                                         
        AllowOverride All                                           
        Require all granted                                         
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews                
    </Directory>   

    <Directory /usr/lib/git>                                     
        AllowOverride All                                           
        Options +ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted                                         
    </Directory>     

    <LocationMatch "/*.git/">                                    
        AuthType Basic                                              
        AuthName "Git Access for GIT LOCAL"                         
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/conf.d/git.passwd                 
        Require valid-user                                          
    </LocationMatch>  

    Alias /git /srv/git                                          
    ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git/git-http-backend/             
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /srv/git                             
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL                                   
</VirtualHost>
```

Repository configuration:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
    sharedRepository = true

[remote "origin"]
    url = http://git.sevlinux.local/git/test.git
```

**/etc/apache2/conf.d/git.passwd** file is created and contains user ayth data.
**/srv/git** directory is owned by wwwrun:www and has 755 permissions (like on my other machine).

I can successfully clone and fetch the repo and access it via web browser after providing corret user:password, but I'm not able to push into it.

Comment: Is it possible that you lack permissions? also, why don't you use git+ssh?

Comment: No, file owner and permissions are exactly the same as on my test server.

I don't use git via ssh because it is more than just problematic to use with Visual Studio...

Comment: I'm talking about permissions in the repository?

Comment: Did you look at your Apache logfiles for some explanations?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek logs are empty. Could it be because of the SSL another subdomain uses?

Comment: @Nidrax there are necessarily logfiles, increase verbosity if necessary and use `--verbose` in `git push` to have more debug.